# Manually deploying a transaction

Tags: transactions, ethereumjs

For educational purposes, I would like to *manually* create and publish a transaction. I want to see what's needed for the transaction and how everything is done.

With my current code, using [Etherscan's transaction broadcaster](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/pushTx) works, it gets accepted at first, but the transaction always gets thrown out of the pending transactions.

I'm using ethereumjs/tx and web3 in the following way, mostly copied from [ethereumjs/tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/tx) with a fresh account with some Ether on it (which is why the nonce is 0):

```
const address = '0x078bB609037E36D43800E1C7531Dbd4f8f1fDd12'

const txParams = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(0),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(2),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(500000),
    to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    value: '0x00',
    data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057',
}

const common = new Common({ chain: 'rinkeby' })
const tx = Transaction.fromTxData(txParams, { common })

const signedTx = tx.sign(privateKey)

const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize()

console.log(serializedTx.toString("hex"))
```

After which I manually publish the serialized transaction using Etherscan.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by using Web3.js, with the following code:

```
web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
        to: '0xF0109fC8DF283027b6285cc889F5aA624EaC1F55',
        value: '1',
        gas: 2000000,
        gasPrice: 1000000000,
        nonce: 3,
        chainId: 4
    }, privateKey)
        .then(console.log);
```

Where `privateKey` is just a plain old hexadecimal private key (prefixed by `0x`.

Take care to use the right `chainId` and `nonce` when creating the transaction this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "replay attack" paramaters that you need to add. You need to add "chainId" because some node reject transactions if you don't specify what chain you want to spend your ETH.

https://chainid.network/

Comment: I just added `chainId: web3.utils.toHex(4)` to `txParams`
 but the signed serialized transaction did not even change. I think the line `const common = new Common({ chain: 'rinkeby' })` already takes care of that.

Comment: Be aware that some libraries didn't implant replay attack so it will be ignored when you sign your transaction. And this transaction can be reject by some block explorer.